# postfix pcre Regex to match and replace substring

Tags: regex, postfix-mta

I'm using Postfix MTA and get important mails in from a broken MTA (which I can't fix because it's not under my control), which sends in the following format:

```
RCPT TO: <+49 (681) 12345678>
```

What I need is:

```
RCPT TO: 4968112345678
```

So I am looking for a regex, which first checks if the string begins with "RCPT TO:" and if this is true, it needs to remove all special characters after it, so that only [a-zA-Z0-9] are left.

Postfix ships an example for such regex'es:

```
# Work around clients that send RCPT TO:<'user@domain'>.
# WARNING: do not lose the parameters that follow the address.
#/^RCPT\s+TO:\s*<'([^[:space:]]+)'>(.*)/     RCPT TO:<$1>$2
```

But after several hours I am unable to adapt it to my needs.

Thanks in advance,
Marco

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems to be, that it is not possible to strip any combination of non-alphanumeric characters in generic case. But for addresses like given in example this regexp should be sufficient:

```
/^[^a-z0-9]*([a-z0-9]+)[^a-z0-9]*([a-z0-9]+)[^a-z0-9]*([a-z0-9]+)$/     $1$2$3
```

You can test regexp maps via postmap command:

```
$ postmap -q "+49 (681) 12345678" pcre:/path/to/regexp_map
4968112345678
```

To use this regexp map add to postfix config

```
canonical_maps = prce:$config_directory/regexp_map
```

Read [ADDRESS_REWRITING_README](http://www.postfix.org/ADDRESS_REWRITING_README.html) about canonical_maps.

Comment: This works as intended. Thanks a lot. What I used was the smtpd_command_filter, which is a low level way of modifying the smtp dialog of broken clients.

Comment: unfortunately, it doesn't work. My input starting with "RCPT TO: " is not matched, just the number without the <> is matched. But this doesn't work.

Comment: @mgabriel For smtpd_command_filter try this regexp: `/^RCPT\s+TO:\s+<[^a-z0-9]*([a-z0-9]+)[^a-z0-9]*([a-z0-9]+)[^a-z0-9]*([a-z0-9]+)>$/      RCPT TO: <$1$2$3>`

Answer (score 1):

Try: `/[^RCPT\sTO\:\s]([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/` filter out all the alphanumeric values resulting in `49 681 12345678`. [[1]](http://www.rubular.com/r/Uapn2m52yk).

Another better way is *blacklisting* all the unwanted chars could also be an option, but doesn't sound optimal.
`/([^<+\)\(>]+)/` results in `RCPT TO: 49 681 12345678`. [[2]](http://www.rubular.com/r/015iyaNG3T)

Or Maybe the best option is to capture any word character (letter, number, underscore) `/(\w+|:)/` resulting in `RCPT TO: 49 681 12345678`. [[3]](http://www.rubular.com/r/mmJZBNbH99)

All of this is tested with rubular and I don't know about Postfix MTA. But i hope this helps.

permalinks:

1. http://www.rubular.com/r/Uapn2m52yk
2. http://www.rubular.com/r/015iyaNG3T
3. http://www.rubular.com/r/mmJZBNbH99

Comment: Didn't test it, as I need to remove the whitespaces too. Thanks for your help.